# Button click confirmation *after* executing part of click handler

Tags: asp.net, .net, event-handling, prompt

I have two dropdown lists,

 one for a list of employees and 

one for a list of teams; 
when a button is clicked the selected employee should be assigned (or re-assigned if they are already assigned to another team) to the selected team. 
In the case that the employee is already assigned to another team (in other words they are being reassigned), 
I'd like to check whether they are the only remaining member of the team they are currently assigned to.
 If so, I'd like to prompt the user with something like 'Reassigning this member will cause *x team* to be empty/removed, are you sure you want to do this?'.
 I know I could do something like this:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to go?');" 
        Text="Confirm" runat="server" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" />
```

But as I understand it, this will cause the prompt to be shown immediately upon the button's click, and isn't dependent on the precondition of the team member being the only remaining member of their current team.

Is there any way I can cause a prompt to be shown conditionally, *after* executing the previously mentioned checks?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

On client click call a ajax method through jquery to check weather or not the team has a single employee.
If it is single then so the confirm box.
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
Or you can create a generic http handler and call it through jQuery
A good link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev

### Edit 1

Suppose you have a page method say checkdata and it returns string
On button client click you call a function like this

```
OnClientClick="return checkData()"
```

And created a function in javascript

```
  function checkData()
  {
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(msg) {
             var msg=msg.d;
             if(msg="true")
             {
                  return confirm("Your message");
             }
          } ....

       });    
  }
```

Here is a good link

[Jquery form check returns true, but need to return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577106/jquery-form-check-returns-true-but-need-to-return-false)

Comment: This looks to be a good start, but I'm still not really clear on how I would show a confirm box without putting it straight into the markup as OnClientClick...would I just add the 'return confirm('Are you sure'); section to the body of the function which is doing the checking?

Comment: Also, my page method would return a boolean...but the data would be returned in json format, correct? If so, isn't json data in string format? Would I just have to do a string comparison for 'true/false'?

Comment: @ChrisV. you can return anything not only json but string also. I am editing my answer.